# count of objects (1116) differs from count of keys (1117)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

How do I ignore the last 2 lines that is in result because that line shows stats like:

```
---
1113 entries, 25351 bytes used, 7417 bytes free.
```

also i am not sure I get this error below:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (1116) differs from count of keys (1117)'

```
NSString *result ...
NSArray *strings = [result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                   [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"=\n"]];

NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

  for (int i = 0; i < strings.count; i+=1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) { // if i is even
                [keys addObject:strings[i]];
            }
            else {
                [values addObject:strings[i-1]];

            }
        }

Sample data:
NC_AllowedWebHosts=
NC_BgeLAN=br1
NC_Doc=/tmp/dhcpd
NC_ExPts=1863
NC_Redirect=1
[...]
bt_binary_custom=/path/to/binaries/directory
bt_blocklist=0
bt_blocklist_url=http://list.g.com/?list=bt_level1
bt_check=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error every time that `strings.count` is odd, because the number of times the loop sees `i % 2 == 0` is greater than the number of times it sees `i % 2 == 1`.

Note that your loop will try inserting identical keys and values, because `strings[i-1]` when `i` is odd refers to the preceding `strings` that has an even index.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
for (int i = 0; i+1 < strings.count; i += 2) {
    [keys addObject:strings[i]];
    [values addObject:strings[i+1]];
}
```

Comment: I have updated the loop as you mentioned. Also added sample data up there. Now when I output values the first 36 values are printed ok but after that (bt_check) "keys" become "values" for the remaining entries. Keys are everything before "=" and values are between "=\r\n"

Comment: @Squirrel That's strange, if the `strings` array is fine, then the above loop should have worked. Add `NSLog(@"%@ %@", strings[i], strings[i+1])` in the loop to show the items as you add them to see what's going on.

Comment: it doesn't print properly. Anyway I can send you a private message so I can send you the input file?

Comment: Sometimes the list has a key/value like this: NC_ExPts=1863==  or NC_Ex=12= and i think that might be causing an issue because i parse like this: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"=\r\n"]   Is there anyway to sort such as NC_ExPts=1863== would output key: NC_ExPts value: 1863==    same with NC_Ex=12= would output key: NC_Ex value: 12=

Comment: @Squirrel Then you need to split the file differently. You may want to post a separate question with the description of your file, and the code that you use to split it. Someone should be able to help you.